# addToBackStack() is not working with getChildFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragmenttransaction

The new fragment which is displayed on a button click is not closing after pressing the back button,instead it is closing the whole application. The button is present inside one of the three tabs. The code of the mainActivity.java, HeroesFragment(the fragment having the three tabs),StrengthHeroesFragment(one of the three tab having the button) is mentioned below.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer=findViewById(R.id.draw_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawer,toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    if (savedInstanceState==null){
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HeroesFragment()).commit();

    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_heroes);}

}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_heroes:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HeroesFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_items:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new ItemsFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_counterpicker:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new CounterPickerFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_news:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new NewsFragment()).commit();
            break;

    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else{
    super.onBackPressed();
    }


}

}
```

HeroesFragment.java (The fragment containing the three tabs)

```
public class HeroesFragment extends Fragment {


private TabLayout tabLayout;
private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
View view;
RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_heroes,container,false);

    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.hero_layout);
    tabLayout=(TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.heroes_tablayout);
    appBarLayout=(AppBarLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.hero_appbar);
    viewPager=(ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.heroes_viewpager);
    ViewPageAdapter adapter=new ViewPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(),1);
    adapter.AddFragment(new StrengthHeroesFragment(),"Strength" );
    adapter.AddFragment(new AgilityHeroesFragment(),"Agility");
    adapter.AddFragment(new IntelligenceHeroesFragment(),"Intelligence");
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Tab 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Tab 2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"tab 3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    return view;


}



}
```

StrengthHeroesFragment.java (the fragment contaning the button )

```
public class StrengthHeroesFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
ImageButton ib1,ib2,ib3,ib4,ib5,ib6;
TextView t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_strength_heroes,container,false);


    ib1=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.abaddon_icon);


   ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HeroDetailsFragment heroDetailsFragment=new HeroDetailsFragment();

            Bundle data=new Bundle();
            data.putString("heroname","Abaddon");
            heroDetailsFragment.setArguments(data);
            FragmentTransaction transaction=getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.strength_hero_layout,heroDetailsFragment).addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
return view;
}


}
```

When i use getFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager() in the StrengthHeroes Fragment it actually works but when i switch to another fragments in the navigation drawer, the content in the tab layout fragments is gone.
I also tried using setPrimaryNavigationFragment() it still didn't worked.
Please help me with it.....
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

use below code instead of super.onBackpress()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else{
     getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

    }
}
```

Comment: Sir after trying that code it doesn't do anything. Neither it closes the fragment nor the app as it was doing it before.